# How to extract elements from nested lists by given index

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists which look like this:

```
[[[12, 15, 0], [13, 15, 25], [14, 15, 25], [16, 16, 66], [18, 15, 55]]]
```

What would be the best way to extract all elements occurring at index position 1. I know I can use a for loop like;

```
for i in list:
    for j in i:
        print j[2]
```

But is there  a more "pythonic" (short /easy /less code/ efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [[[12, 15, 0], [13, 15, 25], [14, 15, 25], [16, 16, 66], [18, 15, 55]]]
>>> [x[1] for x in lst[0]]
[15, 15, 15, 16, 15]
>>>
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
lst = [[[12, 15, 0], [13, 15, 25], [14, 15, 25], [16, 16, 66], [18, 15, 55]]]
final_list = []
for sub_list in lst[0]:
    final_list.append(sub_list[1])
```

except that it is a lot more concise and also avoids all those calls to `list.append` (which means that it is more efficient).

Answer (score 4):

use list comprehension:

```
[ x[1] for x in my_list[0] ]
```

this is more general if nested list is moree...

```
[ y[1] for x in my_list for y in x ]
```